# Transfer points to Affable Greek

Tags: feature-request

How can I transfer all my points to another user (Affable Greek) ? I took him a bet that involved all my points.

Comment: Simple answer: you can't.

Comment: award him a bounty?

Comment: Interesting bet. Too bad you lost. You can give him bounties, but that will only work until you are below 75. You can't award bounties if you are under 75 rep. May I ask what the wager was?

Comment: Betting non transferable property is a great way to play and not lose. (And to discretely probe out your friends mob connections.)

Comment: We're Christian, we don't gamble.

Comment: @Freemason the satirist: Exactly.  The outcome was predestined.  (Seriously, some Christians have no particular problems with gambling in moderation.)

Comment: So that's how he got so many.

Answer (score 8):

I thank you for the [offer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/22943/1039), and so I shall return the favor.  You have transferred 158 points to me, which I will remember as beneficient offering.  In the spirit of camaraderie and general openness to fun, I too award you 158 points.

We are now even :)

Comment: Cool. Thank you. You are a scholar and a gentleman.